# Slanted Navigation

Tags: html, navigation

I am trying to make a navigation menu with slanted shapes as shown in the photo below. Can someone give me any input on the best way to go about creating this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image: Slanted Nav]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way would be to use pseudo elements to create triangles on the edges.

Check out the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HRWqq/

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Some Text</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Some Text</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Some Text</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Some Text</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Some Text</a></li>
</ul>​
```

**CSS:**

```css
li {
    float: left;
    background: #ccc;
    margin-right: 50px;
}
li > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 0 8px;
}
li > a:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border: 20px solid #ccc;
    border-left-color: transparent;
    border-top-color: transparent;
    right: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
li > a:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border: 20px solid #ccc;
    border-right-color: transparent;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}





li:first-child > a {
    background: #aaa;
}
li:first-child > a:after {
    border-top-color: #aaa;
    border-left-color: #aaa;
}

li:last-child > a {
    background: #ddd;
}
li:last-child > a:before{
    border-right-color: #ddd;
    border-bottom-color: #ddd;
}
li:last-child > a:after {
    border: 0;
}
```

​

Comment: Joseph Silber, Is there a way to change the angle of the triangles formed?

Comment: @TechyDude - Sure. Just change the size of the `border-width`, so that the top/bottom is wider than the right/left: http://jsfiddle.net/HRWqq/1/

Comment: Ah ok, thanks again! Is there a way to smooth the edge of these slanted rectangles?

Comment: @TechyDude - They appear pretty smooth to me. Which browser are you using to view my examples? What's your screens pixel density?

Comment: I'm using an iMac display:
iMac:
  Resolution: 2560 x 1440
  Pixel Depth: 32-Bit Color (ARGB8888)
  Main Display: Yes
  Mirror: Off
  Online: Yes
  Built-In: Yes
  Connection Type: DisplayPort

the first jsfiddle you provided looks good, but the second example with steeper triangles looks pixelated. See image: 
http://www.screencast.com/t/cqxuuWK1
http://www.screencast.com/t/SQQjTnoWpS2G

Comment: Do you have any ideas @Joseph Silber? I appreciate all your help. I need a solution that looks smooth on most computers.

Comment: @TechyDude - Unfortunately, no. I'm using a Windows machine, and it looks good on my display. I'm sorry, but I truly don't know any more about this.

Comment: Ok. Thank's for all your help with this.

Answer (score 1):

Use an Image Map. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_map